# Android Load image on ImageView using arraylist

Tags: java, android

This might be a problem that I might overlook again but if you could help me solve it, I will be very thankful.
Using this code to get images from drawable and sending it to Imageview.setImageResource (in which my Imageview is inside a gridview); everything works well

```
private   Integer[] imageIDs = {
            //R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.Image7,
};

//Here is my another code to call imageIDs as ImageResource
ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_picture);
iv.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
//position is a default value of gridview starting from 0
```

Now what I trying to accomplish is to delete that array and convert it to ArrayList simply because need these inside data to be dynamic. And so I've created this new code

```
ArrayList<String> array_image = new ArrayList<String>();
        array_image.add("R.drawable.image6");
        array_image.add("R.drawable.image1");
```

and set the ImageView ImageResource to this code

```
iv.setImageResource(array_image .get(position));
```

I am getting an error saying:

> The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
>   Can you help me fix/figure it out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are defining an ArrayList for Strings. However you need integers as resource identifiers.

Do it instead like this;

```
ArrayList<Integer> array_image = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array_image.add(R.drawable.image6);
array_image.add(R.drawable.image1);
```

Comment: I already tried that sir but still it is giving me an error saying
image6 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: now I am getting this error "The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Object)" on my code iv.setImageResource( array_image.get(position));

Comment: got it 

iv.setImageResource( (Integer)array_image .get(position));

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Janwel try to use this one. This will work most likely.

```
List<Integer> mL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
mL.add(R.drawable.image2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
ArrayList<int> array_image = new ArrayList<int>();
array_image.add(R.drawable.image6);
array_image.add(R.drawable.image1);
```

and then

```
iv.setImageResource(array_image .get(position));
```

Comment: I already tried that sir but still it is giving me an error saying
image6, image1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

if I try to add "" the error is this now
The method add(Integer) in the type ArrayList<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: make sure its ArrayList<int> not ArrayList<String> and you are adding the values without ""

Comment: Why are you posting the same answer auselen gave? And do you realize `ArrayList` cannot be used with primitive types?

Comment: @Benito may be we both are drafting the answer at the same time.. and he posted first and then I posted it.