# setting imageView to new ImageView

Tags: android

I am trying to display a list of three images from my drawable folder by clicks. However, the images.get(i) part gives me an error. I don't understand it. If I replace that with R.drawable.handbag it works but with my arraylist it doesn't work (even though it has the same thing)

```
  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    images.add(R.drawable.handbag);   // these images have been added
    images.add(R.drawable.shoes);
    images.add(R.drawable.tie);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    nextOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);                
    nextOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            i++;
            if (i > 2){
                i = 0;
            }
                image.setImageResource((images.get(i)));

        }

    });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? post your logcat.

Comment: Also please show how you create i and images

Comment: please check your type of arraylist of images

Comment: setImageResource(int) in imageview cannot be applied to (java.lang.object).

Comment: The array list is declared as an ImageView

Comment: Error shows that your are trying to set resource with type object define it require int only array of drawable as my example in answer

Comment: @qaispak try my any of 2 solutions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Load image on ImageView using arraylist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085800/android-load-image-on-imageview-using-arraylist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create images array as below

```
private static int images[]={R.drawable.handbag,R.drawable.shoes,R.drawabletie.tie};
```

and then use as below

```
image.setImageResource((images[i]));
```

or Create ArrayList as below

```
List<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Hey this worked. Can you tell me why the array worked but not the ArrayList?

Comment: Array worked as you are simpling adding int value and retrieving int values. ArrayList doenot work because somewhere there is a type mismatch

Comment: The first one - used a normal array

Comment: Check my comment in your question for which reason it works

Answer (score 2):

Just try like this way

```
int images[]={R.drawable.handbag,R.drawable.shoes,R.drawabletie.tie};
```

Same way

```
List<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
images.add(R.drawable.handbag);   // these images have been added
images.add(R.drawable.shoes);
images.add(R.drawable.tie);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your type of Arraylist to Integer, Like this:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: That did not work as it is still seeing it as "Object" and not integer

Comment: declare it like this

Comment: @ankitagrawal Integer is an OBJECT.

Comment: try my below suggestion

Comment: Integer is a object of type int so you can use  it safely @user5716019